# How to update RecyclerViews in Android in a ClientServer architecture with single activity and mutiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, client-server

I would like to create an App that has clients and a server (so basically they are 2 different apps). In each of the Clients (and the servers) I use a single-activity-multiple-fragments approach and in each App I have a SQLite database. In some fragments I use a RecyclerView. Now the server should be able to update the recylerview in each individual client (and the database) separately and vice versa, meaning that the clients should be able to trigger an update of the recyclerView and databases of the server.

Now my question is, how can I generally do this in Android? I did an Internet search and often for communication **within** an app between different fragments the ViewModel and LiveData approach is used. Now I am wondering, if I can also use these approaches for my purposes? I also  found an official Android developer page about communcation between Apps https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents but here they are using intents and I think that they do not use the single-activity-multiple-fragments approach.

So is it possible to use the ViewModel and LiveData approach for that or do I have to use the intent-approach?

**Update**: I was told that I can't use the ViewModel or LiveData for my purposes. Do you have an idea how I can do what I want? So the clients should be able to send something to the server and the server should be able to send information to the database of the clients and based on that the clients should update their Recyclerview. Can I use sockets for that?

Does nobody have a further idea how I can implement this? As I am struggeling on this question I would highly appreciate your comments and would be quite thankful for your help.

Here you can see a rough sketch of the app architecture.[image]

Comment: I think the live data approach will be the best approach. So whenever there is a change in DB, the data will get notify and recycle view will get updated.

Comment: Thanks abdul for your comment. As I do not have any experience with the live data approach (and model view approach) I would like to ask, whether it is possible to use live data and model view also for communication between apps? And can I also use only LiveData without model view?

Comment: Yes, you can use live data without view models.

Comment: Thanks Abdul for your comment. So would you also advice me to use liveData without the viewmodel? Because I think most often it is used together?

Comment: And can I use liveData for the communication of clients and server apps?

Comment: `Now the server should be able to update the recylerview in each individual client (and the database) separately` That is not possible. A server cannot update anything on client side. Instead a client will request data from a server and then update its database and or some views.

Comment: It looks as if your server runs on an Android device too. Please confirm. Also confirm that server and client run on different devices. If so then using intents (as in your link) makes no sense. Further tell if the devices are used in the same room or that the owners can spread over the world.

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your comments. To be totally honest, I do not know whether the term server and client are really appropiate for my system. Bascially you can think of this as an ordering system in a restaurant. So on the tables you have client devices and there is one central device that collects the orders and sends messages to the clients. So basically they are in the same room.

Comment: Yes, my 'server' runs on an android device and the server and clients run on different devices. The server should be able to change the status of the RecyclerViews on the clients. Any idea how I can do that? Shall I use LiveData (without ModelView) for that?

Comment: @Abdul: You wrote "I think the live data approach will be the best approach. So whenever there is a change in DB, the data will get notify and recycle view will get updated. " So should the server update the local databases of the clients? Is that possible (blackapps here in this post, tolde me that a server can't update anything on the client side)

Comment: As you mentioned that they run on different devices, then it is not possible. You can use firebase real-time DB for this. Whenever there is a change in DB, it will notify.

Comment: Thanks Abdull for your comment. Basically the firebase real-time DB is not an SQL database. I would like to use SQLite for my databases, so this option is not suitable for me. Can you think of any other way how I could do this?

Comment: @blackapps: I hope I provided you the information you needed. Do you have any idea how I can do what I want? I'd appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: `The server should be able to change the status of the RecyclerViews on the clients` As said before: a server can do nothing on a client device. Please reread my comment how to do it instead. And client server is the right naming yes.

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your comment. So is there no way that whenenver on the "server" something is changed that it sends a notify message to the clients? It does not have to be a real server. It could also be just an application that runs on another device.

Comment: Another solution would be that the client request information from the server after a certain time span (e.g. 1 second). But I somehow assume that checking the database of the server every second would make the client app quite slow. What do you think about it and what would you advice me to do.

Comment: @blackapps: Any comments on my last comments? I'd highly appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: You can use push notifications for that. Or if you keep the socket connection open the server can send a message every time.

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Did you not tell me that a server can't send anything to a client? Further, there is still the initial question of mine how to implement this. Would you advice me to use LiveData or the ViewModel to update the? Or could I for example just update the recyclerview every 3 seconds with the current data of the database

Comment: So basically the question is how to implement the communication between the clients and server: LiveData, ViewModel, Intents, or a custom solution? Which one of those is suitable for my purposes?

Comment: @blackapps: Any comments on my last comments? I'd highly appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: @Abdul: Thanks Abdul for your comment. Basically the firebase real-time DB is not an SQL database. I would like to use SQLite for my databases, so your suggested option is not suitable for me. Can you think of any other way how I could do this? I'd highly appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: `So basically the question is how to implement the communication between the clients and server:` It looks you should use sockets for that. Unless you install a webserver on your server. And you were told already that life data and other stuff is useless. And a db is for storage. Not for communication.

Comment: Thanks a lot blackapps for your further answer and effort. In the official Android developer website they recommend using Intents for this (https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send). Would you still prefer the sockets over the intents?

Comment: @blackapps: Are you referring to those sockets https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket? And can a server also send some notifications by using those sockets? What is your take on the Intent approach that is recommended by google (see post before)?

Comment: You have been told before that intents can only be used by apps running on the same device.

Comment: A server could send a notification yes. But notifications are only needed if the user has to be notified. Not if just  some data is exanged.

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your comments and effort. I really appreciate it. "You have been told before that intents can only be used by apps running on the same device. "--> But on the offical Android develper side they recommend sharing data between apps using intents

Comment: "But notifications are only needed if the user has to be notified. Not if just some data is exanged."--> But how can I implement that the server changes the status in the Recyclerview (and the database) of the client?

Comment: @blackapps: any comments on my last comments. I really appreciate it

Comment: The server cannot do anything on a client device. This is the third time i tell you.

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your answer and effort. My question was how would you implement something like this that the server sends a notification to the clients and based on this the clients change their database and recyclerview. Is this not possible to implement?

Comment: Can the client just send a request to the server and the server sends the whole database to the client? Can this be done in 'real time' meaning that the client updates its database every 2 seconds? Would this not lead to high data volumens being communicated?

Comment: @Abdul: Thanks for your suggestions so far. Do you have any other idea how I can implement this? As I am struggeling on this one I'd highly appreciate any further idea and would be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: Firebase setup: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start and you can also look into some article or tutorial to write and read data.

Comment: Thanks Abul for your answer. As said before, I do not want to use the firebase db because I want to use SQLite database and not a No-SQL database. So I was asking for other approaches how I can implement what I want. Do you have any other idea? I'd highly appreciate any further comments from you

Comment: You can also implement thins using sockets, but that would imply that all devices are in the same local network, or that you specify in your router that the "server" device ip is public and redirect requests to it

Comment: Intents are using for one-time requests and get the response and it doesn't work for your challenge. To pass some objects between 2 apps, you can use ContentProvider if both apps are installed on the same device. or you can run an HTTP server in your server app and communicate all data by network call (on the same device). Also, you have online solutions live firebase real-time database, or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Joao and beigirad. So I can just use sockets if I understood correctly? Would you also use LiveData in combination with the Sockets for updating the RecyclerView?

Comment: @beigirad: No the apps are not installed on the same device. However, they are in the same WiFi network. What do you mean by running a HTTP server in my server app? Is it also possible to past e.g. pictures from the server to the clients?

Comment: @VanessaF Yes. Of course. To use HTTP server, devices must be in the same network (Wi-Fi) and able to ping together.

Comment: @VanessaF I think your problem is infrastructure base. Not in presentation layer that you are talking about LiveData, ViewModel, RecyclerView. All of these are playing in presentation layer. Focus on communication between two app.

Comment: Thanks beigirad for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. So what would you advice me to do? Use sockets for the communication between the apps? So can the server-app send new information to the client-app's database and based on this the client-app can update its recyclerview? And of course vice verca. The client should also be able to send a message (in this case an order of a dish) to the server? I'd appreciate any further comments from you

Comment: @beigirad: Any further comments on my last comments? I'd highly appreciate any further comments from you

Comment: Maybe you can also write a full answer. Then I could award the bounty to you (if it answers my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the answer to your question does not fit in one text and requires various articles with details. So I just mentioned some links/articles about the implementation of each part. Also, I try to look at the issue from a higher perspective. And then take a closer look at each part.

I separate your problem into two-part:

### 1. Infrastructure: Communicating data between client and server

According to your comments, these apps are not installed on the same device, but they're in a network and can ping together and the communicated messages are structural data (order of a dish), you have at least 2 options:

1. If the apps have access to the Internet I suggest using [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database):

> The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is
> stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client.
> When you build cross-platform apps with our iOS, Android, and
> JavaScript SDKs, all of your clients share one Realtime Database
> instance and automatically receive updates with the newest data.

also, Google has provided a chat project as [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android). [another example](https://medium.com/@meetpatel12121995/realtime-chat-using-firebase-database-b65ee23f3b6a)

2. Using java socket to run the socket server and connect to it. [article1](https://perihanmirkelam.medium.com/socket-programming-on-android-tcp-server-example-e4552a957c08) , [article2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sending-and-receiving-data-with-sockets-in-android)

### 2. Presentation: reading data and update UI

After implementing send/receive messages, we can use `ViewModel` and keep messages in a LiveData. And then observe the livedata in fragment/activity and show messages in the `RecyclerView`.

Google also has provided a couple of codelabs about these subjects too:

- [Android Kotlin Fundamentals: ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model)
- [Use LiveData with ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-livedata)
- [Android fundamentals: RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-create-recycler-view)

Comment: Thanks beigirad for your answer and the links (I upvoted your answer). Regarding question 1): The Firebase DB is a non-SQL database and I am using SQLite in my apps. Because of this I do not want to use the Firebase DB and I will rather try it with the sockets.

Comment: Regarding question 2): I know how to use a RecyclerView but I have not used LiveData and the ModelView approach at all and I think that they are quite complex and difficult to learn. So my question is whether it is also possible to let the RecyclerView just check its local SQLite database every 3 seconds when the fragment is being displayed and based on the database query just always generate the RecyclerView every 3 seconds. This way it would be easier than using the complex LiveData approach but the problem might be that the Fragment might react slow because of these queries all the time.

Comment: Yes you're right. Using ViewModel and LiveData is an option (that you can deal with it or not). I described it because you mentioned them multiple time in your question and comments.

Comment: @VanessaF Also used db type (Sql base or NoSql) is not important in this scenario. All of them have their selve wrappers and you doesn't face with any low level details. It's up to you about db type.

Comment: Thanks beigirad for your comments and effort. I really appreciate it. So is my descriped approach (see 2nd comment) with updating the recyclerview every 3 seconds by quering the database a feasible solution according to your point of view?

Comment: And regarding the database: I just stated that I am not using the FireBase DB because it is a no-sql database and I use only SQLite databases in my example (instead of the FireBase DB I am going to try it with the sockets). Using a non-sql database would increase the complexity for me as I have no experience whatsoever with no-sql. Because of this I think that sockets are easier.

Comment: Yes, It's possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help beigirad. I accepted your answer and awared the bounty for you. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: @VanessaF Glad I was able to be assistance